# call a javascript function from an ios application

Tags: javascript, html, ios

Advanced thank you for the answers. I have a iOS uibutton function

```
- (IBAction)sendVIN:(id)sender
{}
```

When i click this button the ReceiveVin javascript function has to be called and vin number variable has to be passed as parameters to that function present inside the webpage.

```
     <script>
        function ReceiveVin(vin)
        {
            document.getElementById('vinnumber').value = vin;

        }
</script>
```

This is an online website an can be found at this link "http://tk14.webng.com/autofunds.html"

I cannot use webview for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIWebView's `- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script` method. An example

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('vinnumber').value = vin"];
```

Comment: like i told you i cannot use webview. The data is displayed inside the textfield present inside the website